# How did 'ad' + 'hūc' compound to mean 'so far, thus far, hitherto, still'?

Tags: etymology, morphology

> [ [Adverb   **adhūc** :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adhuc) ]   **Etymology**    
>   [ad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad) "*to*" + [hūc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huc) "*here*"
>
> 1. so far, thus far, hitherto, still
> 2. [2.1] again; [2.2] furthermore; [2.3] moreover; [2.4] besides *(used in scholastic debates to introduce an additional point in one's argument)*
> 3. [3.1] even as, [3.2] while still

Please pardon my laziness; I have not linked the English adverbs above.

How did Compounding of [ad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad) "*to*" +  [hūc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huc) "*here*" generate the meanings in 1?

My conjecture:
 I can imagine a Roman physically pointing to a specific interval or object or moment (which would be 'here' in his/her perspective), to describe everything that had occurred up to that point ('to here' in his/her perspective).

Comment: Why three separate questions on the semantics of *ad huc*? These would best be combined into a single question.

Comment: @TKR Sorry for the multiplicity, I was incertain whether I should question separately the three different sets of meaning. I feared questioning too much in 1 post.

Comment: You can ask several questions about the same narrow topic, but then please explain why the answer you got previously does not answer the new question and how your new (remaining) question differs from the old one. This requires also waiting (about a week?) between the different questions. If the addition is a small one, you can ask it as a comment to an answer. This question and [the other duplicate](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1157/79) could work if you elaborate.