# How did 'ad' + 'hūc' compound to mean 'furthermore; moreover; besides'?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Adverb   **adhūc** :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adhuc) ]   **Etymology**    
>   [ad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad) "*to*" + [hūc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huc) "*here*"
>
> 1. so far, thus far, hitherto, still
> 2. [2.1] again; [2.2] furthermore; [2.3] moreover; [2.4] besides *(used in scholastic debates to introduce an additional point in one's argument)*
> 3. [3.1] even as, [3.2] while still

Please pardon my laziness; I have not linked the English adverbs above.

How did Compounding of [ad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad) "*to*" +  [hūc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huc) "*here*" generate the meanings in 2.2-2.4?

My conjecture: I can imagine two Roman arguers, one of whom points to an argument at some specific location (i.e. 'here') on some writing tool (e.g. wax tablet, piece of wood, papyrus), to which (i.e. to 'here') the other arguer adds more writing.

Comment: See my other comment to your similar question. But consider: *to this point* is similar to 2.2-2.4.  Viz, 'Therefore, X. Furthermore [or: moreover], consider Y' vs 'Therefore, X. To this point, consider Y'.  The 'besides' is mean in the sense of 'in addition', which also works just fine.